# How to parse this date 2018-10-22T2250?

Tags: go, time, timestamp

How to parse this strange datetime 2018-10-22T2250 in golang?
I couldn't find date layout

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse - what have you tried?

Comment: I recieved from another service this timestamp, but I can't parse it

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. What have you tried? You must include the code you need help debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own custom format.  In production, you should also handle the error.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    timeString := "2018-10-22T2250"
    timeFormat := "2006-01-02T1504"

    t, _ := time.Parse(timeFormat, timeString)

    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/iOsO2VlhBoW)

This returns the time in UTC.  You may need to adjust to another timezone, depending on your source.

```
//init the location
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Shanghai")
//localize the time
localTime := t.In(loc)
```